# Permission to read library folder on mobile ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to read all image files on ios devices and i would like to display them in my phonegap gallery application. When i try default phonegap apis i am getting error 1 which is permission error. I understnad that all apps on ios run in a sandbox, however, based on apple developer documentation:

> to obtain access to locations outside of your app’s container
>   directory, you must request appropriate entitlements.

found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Therefore, I should be able to request permission to that folder (same way we are asked to give google permission to read my geo location) so that i can read those images and display them in a mobile app.

However, i cannot find a solution for this besides hints on creating a phonegap plugin to do this, which seems as a hack, since it defetes a purpose of sandboxed application.

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this can be done using the Camera API within PhoneGap using the `Camera.sourceType is Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM` - read more [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

Comment: Yes, i tried that, this only allows selection of single photo from build in prompt. I would like do a bulk search of the entire lib folder and display images in my application automatically.